# Recursive Copy-Local

Tags: .net, dll, msbuild

Yet another question regarding copy-local in msbuild.

The problem I got is that too many assemblies are copied.

I have the following structure:

- A.dll

  - B.dll

    - ThirdParty1.dll
    - ThirdParty2.dll

Now the two third party libraries are referenced by B.dll with local copy set to false. They will be present in the target environment, no matter what.
B.dll is a dependency of A.dll with local copy set to true. I need B.dll where ever I deploy A.dll.

Now the problem is the two third party assemblies are copied as well. I don't want that and I do not understand why this is happening.

One thing that may be important: The projects generating A and B are in different solutions.

Anyone having a idea what is happening and a hint how to solve it?

Comment: Well, that doesn't make much sense.  Delete those DLLs from B's bin\Debug directory.  Rebuild B and make sure they don't come back.

Comment: That may be another important information. There is no "debug" directory. As I develop those DLLs as plugins in another application, they are compiled directly into the directory where the application uses them. Some of the required third party DLLs are already there in this directory. But there are some other third party DLLs that originate from other directories and those are copied (and that is the part I don't want to happen) into the target directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try set

```
<PropertyGroup> 
  <UseCommonOutputDirectory>true</UseCommonOutputDirectory>
</PropertyGroup>
```

In the B project. This shold prevent MsBulid from coping the references to the OutputPath.